# Multithreading in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Is there any way to do multithreading in Actionscript3.

Comment: There are only some libs that provide support for some chain-function/event code execution , but no multithread.

Answer (score 7):

With the release of Flash Player 11.4 and AIR 3.4 there is a new concurrency API with [Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) class.

There is a video tutorial on Workers [here](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=162).

You might also be interested in the [AS3-Workers-Compat](https://github.com/jcward/AS3-Worker-Compat) library that has examples of how to use Workers in a way that is compatible with older versions of Flash Player.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no multi-treading in ActionScript 3.

You need to write your own code to at best ['fake' threading](http://www.over00.com/?p=1240).

Comment: FYI, this was true at the time, but is no longer the case in FP 11.4

Comment: @JeffWard Thanks - do you mind providing some reading materials so I can update my answer?

Comment: Also can whoever downvoted this take into account that it was written at a time when the information was accurate - see the 'answered' date in the bottom right.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, NO, as of later this year, probably, yes:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html

Flash Player "Dolores"
Adobe is planning an additional Flash Player release in the second half of 2012. Code-named "Dolores", this release focuses on enabling features and functionality for the gaming market, as well as improvements for general Flash Player use cases.

Some of the features planned for this release include the following:

- ActionScript workers (enables concurrent ActionScript execution on separate threads)
- Support for advanced profiling
- Support for more hardware-accelerated video cards (from 2005/2006) in order to expand availability of hardware accelerated content
- Improved ActionScript performance when targeting Apple iOS
- Performance index API to inform about performance capabilities of current environment
- Release outside mouse event API
- ActionScript 3 APIs to access the fast-memory opcodes (premium feature when used in conjunction with Stage3D APIs)

Comment: Finally! This will enable people to make games & engines that will be capable of so much more.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the case anymore, might as well update this post. See the Worker class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

Here's a tutorial I found online: http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

It WASN'T, now we have the Actionscript Workers which is the concurrency with actionscript 3. Multi thread in another words... It is available for AIR/Mobile only for now. http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=4368

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, but if you can translate your problem into the texture domain and run a shader (pixel bender) on it and process the results back to your problem domain... Then you could achieve a paralleled execution on the graphics card, but AS3 otherwise only simulates multithreading by giving the highest priority method execution time after each successful method execution.